# Container Views disappear when resizing another Container View in a Storyboard

Tags: ios, ipad, uistoryboard, uicontainerview

This is not a very complex question...but I must be doing something wrong. I just upgraded to XCode 6.1, and I can't seem to resize a Container View on a Storyboard without having every other Container disappear!

I have a screen with multiple container views on it:
[image: view with multiple containers]

Next, I simply try to resize the Container by selecting one of the guides...as I click down on the mouse, all the other containers on the screen disappear:
[image: grabbing edge of one container]

When I release the mouse, the other two containers have disappeared!
[image]

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an xCode 6.1 bug. It has been reported to Apple. The bug is with autolayout, so unchecking "use autolayout" should fix it if you're not using it. Also, you can manually resize the object using the size inspector.

Very annoying bug. I also have been experiencing it.

Comment: Thanks, Ryan, turning off AutoLayout enabled me to work around it.

Comment: The reason is that when we resize any view in the main view it resets all of the width, height, x anyd y coordinates  of the subviews to 0. Thus each subview will be there in the left most top corner with 0 width and 0 height.